# Issue uploading to app store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with uploading an app to the app store.
I have written an app with swift 4 on xcode 9.2 and after uploading an app using application loader I received the following message from apple team.

Error:

> Dear Developer
>
> We have identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your
>   app, "sawfish." Please correct the following issues, then upload
>   again.
>
> Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary
>   submission must be in the PNG format.
>
> ```
>  If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 57x57 pixels.
>  If your application supports the iPad device family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 72x72 pixels.
> ```
>
> For macOS applications, icons included in the binary submission must
>   be in the ICNS format and must include square 512x512 @ 2x image.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I searched about that and found some answers but none of them worked for me.
I put images with 57 and 72 size on CFBundle , Clear , Build and Archive but it is not working for me again  .
what is the problem?

Comment: You can create all icons using https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?mt=12

Comment: Upload your 1024 icon and download ios and android icon from here https://makeappicon.com/

Comment: Did you round the corners of icons yourself? How does your icons look like? These should be square and not the rounded.

Comment: From the apple response, its clear you need to double check the sizes of the provided icons. Make sure you are providing all the sizes and verify no icon has any transparency.

Comment: this work for me. thanks.https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785?mt=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is universal(iPad and iPhone) then you should probably put icons in all of these and follow the correct sizes

[image]

Try double check your file format if it is `.png`